# Why this works using a button and it doesn't work using the onkeypress event

Tags: html, ajax, internet-explorer, servlets, onkeypress

When I try to execute a method using ajax with a button I insert a text at the end of the page in a div and all is right:

[image]

But when I try to execute a method using ajax with the onkeypress of an html text component, it only show the ajax response text and not the other components that I had in the view:

[image]

I need this working on Internet explorer

What is wrong?

**The view:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/views/test.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="test" method="post">
        <div id="div1">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>Code: </span></td>
                    <td><input id="field1" name="field1" onkeypress="javascript:insertOnKeyPress()"
                        type="text" /></td>
                    <td><input id="method" name="method" type="hidden"
                        value="insert" /></td>
                    <td><input id="insert" name="insert" onclick="insertButton();"
                        type="button" value="Insert"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="div2"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**The servlet:**

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@WebServlet("/sc/test")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestServlet.class);

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        this.doPost(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String method = null;
        try {
            method = request.getParameter("method");
            System.out.println(method);
            if (method == null) {
                getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/views/test.jsp").forward(request, response);
            } else if ("insert".equals(method)) {
                System.out.println(request.getParameter("param1"));
                response.setContentType("text/plain");
                response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                response.getWriter().write("response text");
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
        }
    }
}
```

**The javascript file with the methods:**

```
function insertOnKeyPress() {
    var tecla = window.event.keyCode;
    if (tecla == 13) {
        var xmlHttp = false;
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.xmlHttp");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.xmlHttp");
            } catch (E) {
                xmlHttp = false;
            }
        }

        if (!xmlHttp) {
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }

        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
                document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
            }
        };

        xmlHttp.open("POST", "test", true);
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlHttp.send("method=insert&param1=param_test");
    }
}

function insertButton() {
    var xmlHttp = false;
    try {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.xmlHttp");
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.xmlHttp");
        } catch (E) {
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }

    if (!xmlHttp) {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
            document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
        }
    };

    xmlHttp.open("POST", "test", true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttp.send("method=insert&param1=param_test");
}
```

Comment: FYI, there's no point in using `return xmlHttp` in the `onreadystatechange` function.

Comment: You're sending different parameters to the servlet in the two cases. The keypress event sends `param1=param_test`, the button sends `method=insert&param1=param_test`. The servlet returns different results.

Comment: I have updated my question with your suggest but I am still having the same problem

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Both functions do the same thing, they perform an AJAX call and put the response in a DIV. What "other components of the view" are you talking about?

Comment: I just have a html text and a button the problem is the response. please look the images that these components show after the ajax call. The button shows the html text component, the button and the response text, and the onkeypress shows only the response text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `insertOnKeyPress` to prevent the default action of the <kbd>Return</kbd> key, which is to submit the form.

```
if (tecla == 13) {
    var xmlHttp = false;
    window.event.preventDefault();
    ...
```

BTW, you don't need `javascript:` at the beginning of the `onkeypress` attribute. That's never needed in an `onXXX` attribute, it's only needed when you're putting Javascript in an attribute that contains a URL (e.g. `href` or `src`.

Comment: I had problems with window.event.preventDefault() in some IE versions. This fix that compatibility problem: `event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;`

Comment: That's deprecated and you'll get warnings from modern browsers about it, although they'll still do it. The solution that works well on all browsers is to change to `onkeypress="return insertOnKeyPress()"`, and then put `return false` at the end of the `if` block.

Comment: Thanks, I am using a device with an old version of internet explorer